# Comunicación netcat en C para microcontrolador

Tags: c, bash, microcontrolador, netcat

Quiero identificar dos tipos de switches de manera automática con un microcontrolador.

Tengo el siguiente código en bash:

```
echo  ^C | nc $DEFAULT_IP 23 > log.txt
if grep -q "cadena de ejemplo" log.txt;
then
    # OPCION 1
else
    # OPCION 2
fi
```

Lo que hago es:

1. Establezco una conexión mediante `netcat` a la IP determinada por `DEFAULT_IP` por Telnet (puerto 23).
2. Mediante el operador `>` le indico que me guarde la información de la comunicación en un archivo llamado `log.txt`.
3. Mediante `grep` busco si en dicho documento de texto se encuentra el texto `cadena de ejemplo`.
4. Si dicha cadena está, realizo la OPCION 1, sino realizo la OPCION 2.

Hasta aquí todo correcto, y lanzando este script desde un linux conectado a cualquiera de los dos switches me funciona correctamente y me detecta perfectamente el switch que está conectado.

Mi problema viene ahora, cuando quiero implementar este código en C sobre un microcontrolador y se me agotan las ideas de cómo acceder hacer la búsqueda de una cadena de caracteres específica.
La arquitectura para la comunicación Telnet en el microcontrolador la tengo ya funcional y controlada, pero no sé cómo guardar un archivo de texto en el micro, o si mediante una comunicación Telnet se puede guardar información en un buffer para luego realizar un `strncmp`.

**NOTA:** La cadena que yo recojo del `log.txt` es diferente para los dos dispositivos, por lo que pudiendo obtener la cadena de uno me valdría para determinar si se trata del switch 1 o el 2.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si la comunicación ya te funciona, dicha comunicación te permitirá leer datos, seguramente secuencias de bytes. Lo que entiendo que deberías hacer es coger esos bytes y buscar ahí. Para esta tarea puedes usar `strstr` aunque también puedes hacerlo a mano: básicamente iteras por el buffer y, para cada posición, verificas si la cadena a buscar empieza en dicha posición (necesitas dos bucles), si encuentras la cadena ejecutas la opción 1 y en caso contrario la opción 2

Comment: Me lo anoto. Pero, mi duda principal reside en cómo obtener la cadena de caracteres a través de la conexión con la IP. Es decir, en el bash que tengo es bastante fácil crear un fichero (log.txt) con la información que me devuelve el switch, y luego buscar la cadena que yo quiero. Pero lo que me tiene loco es obtener la forma que me permita "hablar" al switch y obtener la cadena. Al no poder guardar un fichero supongo que tendré que emplear un buffer para almacenar la información, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: no existen las conexiones IP, o es una conexión  TCP o es UDP, el primer protocolo deja una conexión persistente y es más pesado, mientras que en el segundo se envían paquetes sueltos. Primero tienes que elegir uno de los dos protocolos, después tocará elegir cómo leer datos de dicha conexión

Comment: Es TCP/IP. Y el puerto 23 para abrir una conexión por Telnet. Soy capaz de comunicar con los switches por Telnet, por lo que dicha arquitectura de control funciona correctamente.

Comment: Y no, no necesitas un archivo para nada. Puedes trabajar en memoria todo el rato. Solo necesitarías un archivo si el tamaño del mensaje superase la cantidad de RAM del sistema. En ese caso podrías volcar todo a un archivo e ir leyendo el archivo por lotes

Comment: Si tienes eso entonces ya tienes el canal abierto... lee los datos que recibas por ese canal

Comment: Pero... ¿Existe alguna función que supla a `netcat` en C? Es decir, quiero hablar a la IP por defecto, preguntarle su nombre por así decirlo, y en función de la cadena que reciba pues ya tomar una decisión u otra. Mi problema reside en que, como digo, no sé cómo sustituir la función `netcat` por otra en C. Por cierto, he probado `strstr` y no hace exactamente lo que quiero, ya que el resultado devuelto es toda la cadena completa desde que encuentra la cadena a buscar hasta el final. Pongo un ejemplo en el siguiente comentario:

Comment: Si la cadena1 es "Hola Pepe, soy yo", y mi cadena2 (a buscar) es "Pepe", el resultado de `strstr(cadena1, cadena2)` es "Pepe, soy yo". Lo que se me ocurre es emplear `strstr` y luego realizar un `strncmp` con la longitud exacta de la cadena que sé que existe, por lo que al resultado de `strstr` en el ejemplo anterior, puedo hacer un `strncmp` de "Pepe" y tan sólo quedarme con esa cadena: PEPE. ¿Es correcto este planteamiento? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: A ver, `strstr` te dice dónde empieza la subcadena `cadena2` en `cadena1`. Es decir, si te da un resultado positivo entonces es que en la posición `n` de `cadena1` se encuentra el mismo contenido que en `cadena2`, luego no tienes que que hacer `strncmp` ni nada por el estilo. Si necesitas el contenido de `cadena1` donde `strstr` te ha dado un resultado, entonces haz uso de `cadena2`, no se si me explico

Comment: Pero `strstr` me devuelve más cadena de la que yo quiero, pero bueno, es un mal menor xD. El problema realmente me reside en cómo obtener la información desde la IP a la que yo me conecto.

Comment: Ahí no hay mucho misterio. Internet tiene demasiados tutoriales sobre cómo montar una conexión entre equipos por TCP

Comment: Lo sé, y en ello estoy a la vez que posteo aquí. Mi problema es básicamente cómo sustituir el código en `bash` que he posteado en la pregunta por uno en C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mi problema es básicamente cómo sustituir el código en bash que he posteado en la pregunta por uno en C

Asumiendo la lectura de datos desde el socket, la solución podría ser así:

```
// Leer datos del socket
#define BUFFER_SIZE 200
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int readResult = read(socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

// Buscar subcadena    
if (strstr(buffer, "cadena de ejemplo") != 0)
{
  // opcion 1
}
else
{
  // opcion 2
}
```

Pero claro, todo esto depende del tamaño del buffer. Si el buffer tuviese que ser demasiado grande se podría desbordar la memoria del sistema que tienes entre manos (asumiendo que estás con microcontroladores) y ahí tendrías que complicar la solución para poder leer por fragmentos. En cualquier caso, como ignoro los requisitos de hardware de tu sistema, esto lo comento como un posible problema

Comment: Intentaré probar si puedo almacenar en un buffer los datos de entrada. Muchas gracias, a priori, por la solución!